# How do I correct this value too long for type character varying(5)?

Tags: postgresql, insert, postgresql-9.4

I created a small development database for practice. It has a table `cities` with columns `cityname` and `state`. The `cityname` in there is 'Cincinnati', long name right?

```
mytestdb=# SELECT * FROM cities;
 cityid |  cityname  | state
--------+------------+-------
 12345  | Cincinnati | Ohio
(1 row)
```

I am unclear as to how and why I am getting this error message upon attempting to add 'San Francisco'.

> ```
> mytestdb=# INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('San Francisco','CA');
> ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(5)
> ```

Comment: Show us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE cities ;`. I would bet that the `cityid` is `varchar(5)`.

Comment: I agree with TypoCube. That's all it can be.

Comment: What @TypoCubeᵀᴹ said. You might want to make a habit of explicitly listing target columns in the insert statements: `INSERT INTO table1  (column1,..) VALUES (...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first, what's the difference..

```
SELECT x, length(x)
FROM ( VALUES
  ('Cincinnati'),
  ('San Francisco')
) AS t(x);
```

Here is the output

```
       x       | length 
---------------+--------
 Cincinnati    |     10
 San Francisco |     13
```

So..

1. San Francisco is three characters longer.
2. They're both over 5 characters.
3. That can't be the problem.

And further, if `Cincinnati` was in a `varchar(5)`, it'd have to get truncated.

So the problem is your `cityid`. It is `varchar(5)`. you probably want that to be an `int` anyway -- it'll be more compact and faster. So `ALTER` the table and fix it.

```
ALTER TABLE cities
  ALTER COLUMN cityid SET DATA TYPE int
  USING cityid::int;
```

As a side note... [maybe someday PostgreSQL will speak column names in error messages.](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/11/818/) until then [at least it's more verbose than SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/54924/2639).

Answer (score 3):

The ***root of the problem*** is ***`INSERT` without target column list***
- which is a popular way to shoot yourself in the foot. Only use this syntax shortcut if you know exactly what you are doing.

[The manual on `INSERT`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html)

> The target column names can be listed in any order. If no list of
>   column names is given at all, the default is all the columns of the
>   table in their declared order; or the first ***N*** column names, if
>   there are only ***N*** columns supplied by the `VALUES` clause or
>   ***query***. The values supplied by the `VALUES` clause or query are associated with the explicit or implicit column list left-to-right.

The ***cure***: list target columns explicitly.

```
INSERT INTO cities (cityname, state)  -- target columns!
VALUES ('San Francisco','CA');
```

This is assuming that `cityid` can be NULL or has a column default.

Typically, the table *should* look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE city  -- personal advice: use singular terms for table names
   city_id  serial PRIMARY KEY
 , cityname text NOT NULL
 , state    text NOT NULL  -- REFERENCES state(state_id)
);
```

Ideally, you also have a table `state` listing all possible states and a [`FOREIGN KEY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) reference to it.

About `serial`:

- [Safely and cleanly rename tables that use serial primary key columns in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14651788/939860)